# Decoding name/value pairs

Tags: php, php5

I have this code in a class sharing a private static array of data. Internally it's encoded, but I need the iterator for a `foreach` loop to show the decoded values.

Is there a native array function that can remap the keys and values via a callback function?

```
public function getIterator( )
{
  $arr = array();
  foreach ( self::$data as $encName => $encValue )
  {
    $name = $this->decode( $encName );
    $value = $this->decode( $encValue );
    $arr[$name] = $value;
  }
  return new ArrayIterator( $arr );
}
```

Comment: I just had a thought to possibly implement `Iterator` instead of `IteratorAggregate` which would reduce the need for duplicating the array before iterating, and instead, decode during the iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementing `Iterator` is the way to go in my opinion. As for your question, [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) would allow you to decode the values but not the keys. But you can combine that with other array operations to get the desired result.

```
public function decodeArray($array) {
    $decode = array($this, 'decode');
    return array_combine(
            array_map(array_keys($array), $decode),
            array_map(array_values($array), $decode)
        );
}
```